# SendOnBehalfOf - User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header

Tags: docusignapi

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication=[<DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>UserId from CheckAccountMemberResult</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>apiusername</Username><Password>passs</Password><IntegratorKey>apikey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>]}
```

I was testing [“Send On Behalf Of”](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/Acting%20As%20Other%20Account%20Users.htm) feature and received an error in the subject.
Please let me know what I am missing?

Do I have to take the Auth Token route? If that is the case, do I have to use operating user's password as opposed api user's password. I am confused.

Thanks
N

Update: Another surprise. The authentication was working fine for the API credentials (without the SendOnBehalfOf tag). Now it's not. Hope Docusign is not doing any maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Send On Behalf Of with SOAP, the sending user is identified within the Email element of the authentication header.  For example, let's say that my API user name is "apiuser@example.com" and my sending user name is "sender@example.com".  If using the DSAPI.asmx endpoint, the authentication header would look like this:

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>[sender@example.com]apiuser@example.com</Username><Password>mypassword</Password><IntegratorKey>EXPL-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

When using WS-Security and the API.asmx endpoint, a similar structure is used:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>[EXPL-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000][sender@example.com]apiuser@example.com</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>mypassword</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce>00000000000000000000000000000000</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2013-10-29T20:37:59.241468Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

For reference, OAuth2 is not required and is not supported in the SOAP API at this time.

Comment: I just sent the request with header:`Address: https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[application/xml], SOAPAction=["http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateAndSendEnvelope"], X-DocuSign-Authentication=[<DocuSignCredentials><Username>apiuser@a.com</Username><Password>********</Password><IntegratorKey>TRAN-00000000000000000</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>]}`  . The response is again `<faultstring>User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header</faultstring>`. Can we know why our requests are being rejected? Thanks!

Comment: Can you get the raw request?  What you posted appears to be the dump of a data structure (dictionary hold arrays?) so I want to be sure it is making it into the request properly.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this. The header was added at a later stage while preparing the request. In case anyone is using Apache CXF client, please use `Phase.POST_LOGICAL` in the interceptor to populate X-DocuSign-Authentication header. Again, Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the "**Send On Behalf Of Functionality in the DocuSign REST API**" section (p16-18) of the DocuSign REST API Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf)?  This content provides a decent overview of how to use SOBO with the DocuSign REST API, and even includes some examples.

Comment: I did exactly mentioned under: "Example using Email Address" section Page 17. BTW, I am using SOAP though.

Comment: Ah, okay -- SOAP API...got it.  (The documentation page you linked to in your question is from the REST API guide -- therefore may not apply equally to the SOAP API.)  Perhaps this documentation will help you then:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20Guide.pdf.  I do notice that all of the SOBO examples in the DocuSign SOAP API documentation show credentials being passed in the SOAP Header via WS-Security UsernameToken (not in the HTTP Header via X-DocuSign-Authentcation).

Comment: "The **DSAPI.asmx** and AccountManagement.asmx end points **require** the HTTP **Header** authentication method" from the [docs](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/Authentication.htm%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication|_____0)

Comment: Also please read my first comment, I cannot authenticate with API credentials as well.